# How do I insert C# into an alert box (or something similar)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-4

I am a super beginner with C# and Visual Studio. I am creating a razor webpage designed to grab SQL values from a drop-down list and display them below, basically generating a code for the user based off of what they picked in the drop-downs. I would like the code to be placed in an alert box or something similar, but it won't work when I encapsulate all of it. I have tried applying the HTML/CSS separately on all of the variables, but it ends up looking really weird.

Can someone please give me a hint on how to get all of the generated code inside of an alert box or something similar? (right now the code is appearing outside of the alert box because it doesn't like the SQL/C# variables...)

```
   <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-primary">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="alert-heading" text-align="center">Code generated:</h4>
                    <p class="mb-0">Copy and paste the code below.</p>
    </div>

{
    foreach (var row in db.Query(sql_getData7))
    {@row.TEST1-}

    foreach (var row in db.Query(sql_getData5))
    {@row.TEST2-}

    foreach (var row in db.Query(sql_getData6))
    {@row.TEST3}
}
```

Thank you for any help!!

Comment: Where and how are you trying to alert it ? What is happening with your current approach ? Are you getting an error in browser console ? What does it say ?

Comment: No, there is no error. The alert box will appear, but will only include the "Code generate: / Copy and paste the code below" portion of the text. I want to include the code that is generated as well (the variable rows in the foreach statements), but if I put the </div> tag at the end of the code I provided, Visual Studio will not accept it and throws an error.

Comment: What does `db.Query` return? What is `row.TEST1`, etc.?

Comment: Why is a View executing database code?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve? C# code written in the view is executed at the server side so you will not see that code when you browse the page. What you see is the result of the execution of that c# code.

Comment: Like I said, I am a super beginner. This is what the programmer guy at work has taught me... so db.query returns the query that generates the selected code from the dropdownlist that the user chooses. So far example, in dropdown 1, if they choose a value equal to 123, dropdown 2 =456, dropdown 3 = 789, the @row will return 123-456-789. Please help learn if there is a better way, I don't want to be stuck doing this completely wrong and learning bad habits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest you to use razor syntax (write C# on View) Please try this coding style below.

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-primary">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
     <h4 class="alert-heading" text-align="center">Code generated:</h4>

@{
   foreach (var row in db.Query(sql_getData7)) {
       <p class="mb-0">@row.TEST1</p>
   }
}

@{
   foreach (var row in db.Query(sql_getData5)) {
       <p class="mb-0">@row.TEST2</p>
   }
}

@{
   foreach (var row in db.Query(sql_getData6)) {
       <p class="mb-0">@row.TEST3</p>
   }
}
</div>
```